# I can't get Oracle execution plan in prod database

Tags: database, oracle, sql-execution-plan

I'm connecting to a production database with a read-only separate account (no DBA privileges), and I can't get the execution plan for a query. When I try:

```
explain plan for
select * from my_table where id = 10;

select plan_table_output from
  table(dbms_xplan.display('plan_table',null,'typical'));
```

I get different plans for unrelated queries every time. I guess there are so many queries per second that the plan gets immediately replaced by other ones.

Then, I tried adding a "statement ID":

```
explain plan set statement_id = 'st1' for
select * from my_table where id = 10;

select plan_table_output from
  table(dbms_xplan.display('plan_table','st1','typical'));
```

but I get the error:

> Error: cannot fetch plan for statement_id 'st1'

What's the easiest and consistent way of retrieving an execution plan in a highly concurrent db?

Comment: How was `plan_table` created? It should be a global temporary table. Are you using pooled connections somehow? `explain plan for` should not be part of normal application code, so it would be surprising either way.

Comment: If you want to see the real execution plan that is actually being used, you should be using `dbms_xplan.display_cursor` with the `sql_id`. `explain plan` can easily be misleading

Comment: @AndrewSayer I don't know how the plan_table was created (this is Oracle at AWS, if that's useful). Unfortunately I'm a mere mortal (don't have privileges) and can't modify it. Does this mean there are multiple ways of creating this table?

Comment: Wait... in which schema is the table created? In my read-only user one, or the one from the main service account? How can I tell?

Comment: `select * from all_tables where table_name ='PLAN_TABLE';`

Comment: OK, ran the query and it's in the service account schema (main shared one), not my read-only account.

Comment: Do you mean sys? I’m not familiar with how AWS sets up Oracle, but the fundamentals should be like a normal Oracle instance. What does the `temporary` column say for it? Also check the view `all_synonyms` For a plan_table synonym, new databases on newer releases make one for you (as a GTT)

Answer (score 0):

This is late but I found this via an internet search on the error.  First issue is the explain itself fails because is invalid.  With a short query like the above you would see the error but on a longer query where you script the explains and query you might miss the error messages.  Second, set serveroutput being on or your disabling it between the explain and results query will block getting the results.  Hope this helps somebody.